# How to find wrong infix expression?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have to convert infix expression to postfix. My Infix to Postfix code is working without any error. But I have to also find the wrong infix expression. How to solve this problem?

Here is my code : ( I have used my custom stack file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stacktype.cpp"
using namespace std;

string infixToPostFix(string infix);
int higherPrecedenceValidate(char op1, char op2);
int getPrecedence(char op);
int evaluatePostFix(string postfix);

int main()
{
    string infix,postfix;
    int result;
    cin >> infix;
    postfix = infixToPostFix(infix);
    cout << postfix <<endl;
    result = evaluatePostFix(postfix);
    cout << "result: " << result << endl; 

}


string infixToPostFix(string infix){
    StackType<char> operators;
    string postfix;
    for(int i = 0; i < infix.size(); i++){
        // Checking Operator
        if(infix[i] == '+' || infix[i] == '-' || infix[i] == '*' || infix[i] == '/'){
            while (!operators.IsEmpty() && higherPrecedenceValidate(operators.Top(),infix[i]))
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
                operators.Pop();
            }
            operators.Push(infix[i]);

        }
        // Checking Operand
        else if(infix[i] >= '0' && infix[i] <= '9')
        {
            postfix = postfix + infix[i];

        }
        //Checking open bracket
        else if(infix[i] == '(' ){
            operators.Push(infix[i]);
        }

        //Checking closing bracket
        else if(infix[i] == ')' ){
            while (!operators.IsEmpty() && operators.Top() != '(')
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
                operators.Pop();
            }
            // poping the opening bracket
            operators.Pop();
        }


    }
    // poping rest of element from the stack..
    while (!operators.IsEmpty())
    {
        postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
        operators.Pop();
    }
    return postfix;
}

int evaluatePostFix(string postfix){
    StackType<int> finalNumbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); i++){
        // Checking Operator
        if(postfix[i] == '+' || postfix[i] == '-' || postfix[i] == '*' || postfix[i] == '/'){
            int resultOfTwoNumber;
            int number2 = finalNumbers.Top();
            finalNumbers.Pop();
            int number1 = finalNumbers.Top();
            finalNumbers.Pop();
            switch (postfix[i])
            {
                case '+':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 + number2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 - number2;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 * number2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 / number2;
                    break;
            }
            finalNumbers.Push(resultOfTwoNumber);

        }
        // Checking Operand
        else if(postfix[i] >= '0' && postfix[i] <= '9')
        {
            finalNumbers.Push(postfix[i] - '0');

        }
    }
    return finalNumbers.Top();
}


int higherPrecedenceValidate(char operator1, char operator2)
{
    int op1 = getPrecedence(operator1);
    int op2 = getPrecedence(operator2);
    if(op1 == op2)
        return true;
    return op1 > op2 ?  true: false;
}

int getPrecedence(char op)
{
    int weight = 0;
    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        weight = 1;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        weight = 2;
        break;
    }
    return weight;
}
```

> Now I solved this problem. Here is my wrong infix expression checking code with infix to postfix and postfix to result evalution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stacktype.cpp"
using namespace std;

string infixToPostFix(string infix);
int higherPrecedenceValidate(char op1, char op2);
int getPrecedence(char op);
int evaluatePostFix(string postfix);

int main()
{
    string infix,postfix;
    int result;
    cout << "Infix: ";
    cin >> infix;
    postfix = infixToPostFix(infix);
    cout << "\nPostfix: " << postfix << endl << endl;
    if(postfix != "Wrong Expression"){
        result = evaluatePostFix(postfix);
        cout << "Result: " << result << endl << endl; 
    }


}


string infixToPostFix(string infix){
    StackType<char> operators;
    bool isMathOperatorRepeated = false;
    bool isOperaendRepeated = false;
    string postfix;
    for(int i = 0; i < infix.size(); i++){
        // Checking Operator
        if(infix[i] == '+' || infix[i] == '-' || infix[i] == '*' || infix[i] == '/'){
            if(isMathOperatorRepeated){
                postfix = "Wrong Expression";

                /* 
                After this for loop there is while loop
                which is checking rest of the char and add it with postfix string .
                So this pushed char should be pop out 
                beacuse infix expression is wrong.
                */

                while (!operators.IsEmpty())
                {
                    operators.Pop();
                }
                break;
            }
            while (!operators.IsEmpty() && higherPrecedenceValidate(operators.Top(),infix[i]))
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
                operators.Pop();
            }
            operators.Push(infix[i]);
            isMathOperatorRepeated = true;
            isOperaendRepeated = false;

        }
        // Checking Operand
        else if(infix[i] >= '0' && infix[i] <= '9')
        {
            if(isOperaendRepeated){
                postfix = "Wrong Expression";

                /* 
                After this for loop there is while loop
                which is checking rest of the char and add it with postfix string .
                So this pushed char should be pop out 
                beacuse infix expression is wrong.
                */

                while (!operators.IsEmpty())
                {
                    operators.Pop();
                }
                break;
            }
            postfix = postfix + infix[i];
            isMathOperatorRepeated = false;
            isOperaendRepeated = true;

        }
        //Checking open bracket
        else if(infix[i] == '(' ){
            operators.Push(infix[i]);
            isMathOperatorRepeated = false;
            isOperaendRepeated = false;
        }

        //Checking closing bracket
        else if(infix[i] == ')' ){

            while (!operators.IsEmpty() && operators.Top() != '(')
            {
                postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
                operators.Pop();
            }

            /*
            checking stack beacuse we know 
            that if the infix char is ')'  
            and the stack is empty then the infix expression is wrong

            */
            if(operators.IsEmpty()){
                postfix = "Wrong Expression";
                break;

            }
            else{
                operators.Pop();
            }
            // poping the opening bracket
            isMathOperatorRepeated = false;
            isOperaendRepeated = false;
        }

        // checking that infix expression has invalid char
        else{
            postfix = "Wrong Expression";

            /* 
                After this for loop there is while loop
                which is checking rest of the char in stack.
                So this pushed char should be pop out 
                beacuse infix expression is wrong.
            */
            while (!operators.IsEmpty())
            {
                operators.Pop();
            }
            break;
        }


    }
    // poping rest of element from the stack..
    while (!operators.IsEmpty())
    {
        if(operators.Top() == '('){
            postfix = "Wrong Expression";
            break;
        }
        else{
            postfix = postfix + operators.Top();
            operators.Pop();
        }
    }
    return postfix;
}

int evaluatePostFix(string postfix){
    StackType<int> finalNumbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); i++){
        // Checking Operator
        if(postfix[i] == '+' || postfix[i] == '-' || postfix[i] == '*' || postfix[i] == '/'){
            int resultOfTwoNumber;
            int number2 = finalNumbers.Top();
            finalNumbers.Pop();
            int number1 = finalNumbers.Top();
            finalNumbers.Pop();
            switch (postfix[i])
            {
                case '+':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 + number2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 - number2;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 * number2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    resultOfTwoNumber = number1 / number2;
                    break;
            }
            finalNumbers.Push(resultOfTwoNumber);

        }
        // Checking Operand
        else if(postfix[i] >= '0' && postfix[i] <= '9')
        {
            finalNumbers.Push(postfix[i] - '0');

        }
    }
    return finalNumbers.Top();
}


int higherPrecedenceValidate(char operator1, char operator2)
{
    int op1 = getPrecedence(operator1);
    int op2 = getPrecedence(operator2);
    if(op1 == op2)
        return true;
    return op1 > op2 ?  true: false;
}

int getPrecedence(char op)
{
    int weight = 0;
    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        weight = 1;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        weight = 2;
        break;
    }
    return weight;
}
```

Comment: Add an `else` last in the `else if` chain, where you report an error? Every time you detect something that's not correct you should report it, and for that you need to add `else` clauses (like I said before) or `default` cases or generally just tell the user when something unexpected happened.

Comment: Also add `default` case to all switch statements.

Comment: if the infix expression starts with `+`, `*`, `/`, it is still `wrong expression`.

Comment: why can't operand repeat? `22+233` could be transfered to `22 223 +`. you need allow this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things below that you should check as you do the conversion to decide if the infix expression is valid:

- Add the final `else` to the chain determining the character type, i.e. an operator, a digit, or a parenthesis. Your code would hit that branch when the character is not recognized, meaning that the infix expression is invalid. You may need to add another "valid" branch to allow whitespace.
- Add a check to see that an operator is preceded by another operator, as in `2 + * 3`. You can do it with a `bool` flag set in the "this is an operator" branch, and reset everywhere else.
- Add a check that the stack is not empty before popping the opening bracket. The `while` loop above it can end for two reasons - the stack gets empty, or you find the corresponding opening parenthesis. If the loop ends because the stack is empty, the expression segment has more closing parentheses than opening parentheses, and the expression is invalid.
- Add a check that none of the operators you pop during the final "unwinding" of the stack is a parenthesis. If you find a parenthesis on the stack at the end, the expression has more opening parenthesis than closing parenthesis, hence it is invalid.

When you detect that the expression is invalid, throw an exception, or return a special `string` to indicate that the conversion has failed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your instruction really worked for me :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `2 + - 3`, and you should *not* try to detect this case separately. A correct expression parser will detect the illegal cases already. But this is not one of them. Consider also `------------------2`.

Comment: @EJP This was a poor choice of operators, as infix pluses and minuses double as unary sign operators. As far as "correct parsers detecting illegal cases" goes, this question has very little to do with "correct parsers", it's very specific to stack-based conversion exercise.

Comment: if the infix expression starts with `+`, `*`, `/`, is it still wrong infix? if i want to transfer a expression like `22 + 33 ` to `22 33 +`, how can i process it?